# Excluding specific folders while copying stuffs from one directory to another

Tags: shell-script, find, ksh, cp, subversion

I have to copy contents of some code from one folder called `aim-db-dir` to another called `aim-db-dir_nosvn`. `aim-db-dir` contains .svn folders in all the directories (and subdirectories) and these .svn folders contain some folders and files which I am not concerned with. I want to copy everything in the directories and subdirectories under `aim-db-dir` except the .svn folders and its contents.

So my question is how do I do this. I read about `rsync` but am not sure we can exclude directory and file patterns. Also I tried to do using find and cp but I am missing on something.

The command I am trying is something like (doesn't work)-

```
find aim-db-dir/* -not -name ".svn" | sed -n 's|^aim-db-dir/||p' -exec cp -R "{}" "aim-db-dir_nosvn/{}" \;
```

I also thought of using `xargs` but I never used so not sure if it can be made use of. Multiple solutions are appreciated!

Comment: The `gnu tar` program has a `--exclude-vcs` option, which will avoid all `.svn` directories. You can pipe `tar` to/from stdout/stdin, and use `-C` to get to the correct starting directory.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `find` and GNU `cpio`:

```
find /path/to/aim-db-dir -name .svn -prune -o -print0 | cpio -padmv0 /path/to/aim-db-dir_nosvn
```

With `rsync`:

```
rsync -av -exclude=.svn /path/to/aim-db-dir/ /path/to/aim-db-dir_nosvn
```

The trailing slash in the `/path/to/aim-db-dir/` is important, without it a directory named `aim-db-dir` is created in `aim-db-dir_nosvn`.

With GNU `tar`:

```
tar cpf - --exclude-vcs -C /path/to/aim-db-dir . | tar xvpf - -C /path/to/aim-db-dir_nosvn
```

There is a limit on the maximum length of the paths of the files you can copy with `tar`, coming from a limitation in the underlying PAX format.